# Why equating forces give wrong answer here but using work-energy theorem gives the correcct answer?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

Question: A block of Mass m is connected to another block of mass M by a mass-less spring of spring constant k . The blocks are kept on a smooth horizontal plane and are at rest. The spring is unstretched when a constant force F starts acting on the block of mass M(horizontally) to pull it. Find the maximum extension of the spring.

[image]

Here I assumed that max. extension(x) will be produced when both the blocks would be moving with constant and same acceleration. Then by considering the FBD diagram of the blocks m and M, I formed this equation

$\Large \frac{kx}{m}= \frac{F-kx}{M}$

and hence I get the value of x as

$\Large x=\frac{mF}{k(m+M)}$

$\large Solution$

by conservation of energy
In the reference frame of center of mass.

For block 'm', we have two forces acting $mF/(m+M)$ and $kx$, in opposite directions.

For block 'M' we have three forces acting $MF/(m+M)$ and $kx$, and $F$ in the opposite direction.

Assuming m moves a max distance x_1 from CM
M moves a distance x_2 from CM.
Then work done by external force will be

$$W=mF(x_1+x_2)/(m+M)$$

This will be stored as the internal energy, therefore

$$1/2·k·(x_1+x_2)^2=W$$

On solving this we get

$$x_1+x_2=2mF/(k(m+M))$$

But my method is not correct.
Can someone please help me out understand why this approach is not correct?

(When I looked up for the solution, the correct answer given was  $\large \frac{2mF}{k(m+M)}$,  by solving it from reference frame as COM, by using work-energy theorem but if that is the answer both the blocks would have different accelerations .)

Comment: I think there is a typo in "*Assuming m moves a max distance x_1 from CM M moves a distance x_2 from CM.*"